# What is it called? a socket? an extension cord? or both?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request

> **[socket](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/socket)**: 1 a place in a wall where you can connect electrical equipment to the supply of electricity
>
> SYN power point British English, outlet American English

---

> [**exˈtension ˌlead**](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/extension-lead) British English, extension cord American English noun
>   [countable]     an additional piece of electric wire that you attach
>   to another wire to make a very long one  SYN extension

---

So, normally, a socket is on a wall & an extension cord is an electric wire.

But people invented one which combines the both.

See this picture

[image]

**What should I call the one showed in the picture?**

**is it a socket (nut not on the wall)? or is it an extension cord (but not just a cord, it has many points that we can plug other electric equipment in)?**

Comment: In my idiolect the whole thing is called a “powerboard”.  It’s made up of sockets, a plug with a lead/cord/cable and switches. I might say “it’s a powerboard with a long extension cord” because that part is unusually long in my experience. https://www.bunnings.com.au/our-range/lighting-electrical/electrical/powerboards

Comment: @OrbitalAussie, so, we say "there are 4 sockets on the powerboard" right? each socket is a place that 1 device can be plugged in or each socket can have many holes for plugging many devices?

Comment: Yes, four “sockets” or more probably and technically “outlets”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call that entire device "a power strip with a long cord."

If the fact that it has a long cord isn't important, I would just call it "a power strip." On the other hand, I might call the whole device "an extension cord," since it serves the purpose of an extension cord.

I would call the three parts of that device "the plug" (the part that plugs into the wall), "the body" (the part that you can plug several devices into), and "the cord" (the cable that connects the plug to the body).

This power strip has four sockets, which are also called outlets. You can plug one device into each socket.

I've never heard the word "powerboard" before; maybe that's an Australian word. I live in the United States.

Answer (score 1):

The socket is the holes, the place where you would plug something in.

The cord is the wire that extends.

You can also refer to the entire thing as an "power strip" or "extension cord" more generally if you're not talking about any specific part.

Comment: Are you using American English? What do you call something (with a short cord) that allows many devices to be connected to a single power outlet?

Comment: @OrbitalAussie Yep, American English. I guess you'd call it a "power strip", actually, or maybe an "extension cord" - either one would apply. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Definitely power strip. Maybe some regions use "extension cord" interchangeably, but to me a cord has two ends.

Comment: so, we say "there are 4 sockets on it" right? each socket is a place that 1 device can be plugged in or each socket can have many holes for plugging many devices?

Comment: @Tom Yep, a socket is where you plug the device. I.e. a power strip has multiple sockets and a cord

Answer (score -1):

We may call it an electric Socket Extension.

Comment: While this may be correct, we like our answers to be backed up by references. You can [edit] your answer to include one (e.g. an online dictionary). See the Help Center article [answer].